# How do I get Visual Studio Code to pause on exit when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code

Try as I might I can't find a way to get Visual Studio Code to pause at the end of debugging. The console window just disappears, taking any output with it. If I run the program over and over again I can see some text flashing up, but I can't read it in the millisecond it appears for.

I **can** pause on startup. That works. However the output I'm interested in appears to be generated after I've returned out of the last function in the call stack, so stepping through doesn't seem to help.

I'm using 0.8.0.

How do I get Visual Studio Code to pause on exit when debugging?

Comment: If you're actually stepping through the code, then put a breakpoint at the end of the main function. If you're not, just start with `Ctrl+F5` (start without debugging) - then it will pause at the end all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

As of [version 1.0.0](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download), the debug console remains up for me even after my program finishes running. Try it in the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

This may be solvable by setting:

```json
"debug.console.closeOnEnd": false
```