# C++ in VSCode - Getting Started

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble getting a simple C++ script to run in VSCode (I'm new to both). I followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-compile-c-code) instructions, and the status bar displays "C++" on the bottom right of the screen, next to the smiley face. I then ran the following script:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, the script's path flashes on the output screen and disappears. I expected it to display "Hello World" in the output.

I can run the script from the command window (I'm in Ubuntu) and the output file behaves as expected when executed.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645271/how-do-i-get-visual-studio-code-to-pause-on-exit-when-debugging/73369616#73369616

Answer (score 0):

Your program prints message to STDOUT and exits. Add some kind of wait (you can read STDIN for example) if you want to see its output.

PS: Why do you call your program "script"?

Comment: I added cin.ignore(); before return 0; but I get the same behavior. When I run it now in the command window, it waits for me to hit enter as expected.

Comment: I think you could argue that this is a script, as it just runs start to finish, straight through :) 
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language, paragraphs 2-3 in the 'Characteristics' section.

Comment: Can you show the script you added as a task? Script from the SO post you mentioned only builds the file, it doesn't run the compiled program.

Comment: Ah, that might be what I'm getting confused here. I'm not sure what you mean by "script you added as a task" - all I've done is hit Ctrl+Shift+B on the script I showed in my post. How do I run it after it builds? Can I run it within VSCode?

Comment: You referenced the post, where the answer suggests pasting some code into `tasks.json`. If you pasted that code as is, your `tasks.json` only builds your sources by invoking `make all` in current directory. I'm not sure VSCode can debug C++ code. I'd suggest you try QtCreator, Eclipse+CDT, KDevelop or any other IDE designed to develop and debug C++ code.